# What's the trick to get JNA to interface with 3rd party DLLs?

Tags: java, jna

I'm getting the following error when trying to interface with a Magtek 32-bit DLL.

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library 'MCPAPI': The specified module could not be found.
```

I have no problem interfacing with user32.dll in the same code (just tweaking the DLL name and interface).  Seems to indicate that the DLL can't be found, but it's most definitely in my jna.library.path.  I've even gone as far as dumping it into the Windows system directory, next to user32, without success.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Update: If I point jna.library.path at C:\Windows instead of at the separate install directory of the DLL, I get "java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Windows\MCPAPI.DLL: Can't find dependent libraries" instead.  This appears to be an improvement anyways...  At least it's finding the library, just not whatever it depends on...

Comment: the DLL is the self generated one or you have generated it?Its most probable that the dependency files were not added at the time of dll generation ...I had the same issue for JNI

Comment: It's supplied by a third party (not myself).  Any way around missing dependency files?  Perhaps they exist elsewhere, what should I look for?

Comment: i dont know much about what kind of dependencies you might play with,but for me i compiled my c code using gcc and used -I flag to add all the dependency files(i had to enter jdk files as the dependency as i was to make a JNI call to the C function)...see if you can get the code of the file and try recompiling it...

Comment: Still no luck interfacing with their DLL.  Looks like I'm going to have to write my own HID controllers for this device.

Answer (score 1):

jna.library.path will only influence loading of libraries directly referenced.  Dependent libraries must be found either in the same directory as the explicitly loaded one, or in PATH.

For your example to work, MCPAPI must be in either jna.library.path or PATH, and its dependent libraries must be either in the same directory or in PATH.

Comment: I've tried specifying it in the jna.library.path, PATH, and have even moved the files into the same directory as other ones that *do* load.  :-(  Still no solution on this, but I haven't been trying much lately as the project is now on hold pending higher priority project completion.

Comment: What does depends.exe indicate as the full list of dependent dlls for MCPAPI?

Comment: Where do I get "depends.exe"?  I don't seem to have that on my system.

Comment: c'mon, google "depends.exe" leads you straight to "Dependency Walker"... http://www.dependencywalker.com/

Comment: The way you just put "depends.exe" in your comment made it look like it was something that's supposed to be built into the system.  Saying, "get and use Dependency Walker" would have been much more helpful.

Comment: I have a tendency to forget that it's not included with any dev environment.

Comment: Impressive.  The dependencies list is pages long and includes a couple that are flagged as missing.  Yet, the demo app works and mine doesn't.  :-)

Comment: Does your demo app dynamically load the library or is it directly linked to it?  Try re-writing the demo app to instead dynamically load the library and see what you get.

Comment: What are the parameters passed to the LoadLibrary/LoadLibraryEx call?  JNA uses LOAD_WITH_ALTERED_SEARCH_PATH so that the current directory is searched prior to everything in PATH (see native/dispatch.c in the source).

Answer (score 0):

If you run a 64bit jvm you cannot load 32bit dll's. If thats the case, install 32bit jvm

Comment: I'm using the 32-bit JVM and am successfully able to connect with user32 in System 32 (which I believe is a 32-bit DLL?).

Answer (score 0):

try using System.load(path\to\library) instead System.loadLibrary().

Comment: I'm using com.sun.jna.Native.loadlibrary, there's no Native.load available.  Trying to use any of the System loads results in errors too.